# Inner join on four tables on MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to do an inner join on four tables in [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL). The table names are:

```
question (id_question, question_text, id_standard)
standard (id_standard, standardtext)
organisation_standard(id_organisation,id_organisation,id_standard)
organisation (id_organisation, organisation_name)
```

This is my query and it's giving me repetitive values:

```
select distinct a.question_text, d.organisation_name
from question a
inner join standard b on a.id_standard = b.id_standard
inner join organisation_standard c on b.id_standard= c.id_standard
inner join organisation d on c.id_organisation = d.id_organisation
where a.id_standard = 18;
```

How can I avoid the repetitive values?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Why do you join the table `standard` if you don't select anything from it and the tables `question` and `organisation_standard` also contain the column `id_standard`?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community! Stack Overflow is a _question_ and _answer_ site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The emphasis being: a posted question should be an actual _question_. (But thanks, I guess, for posting the current status of your latest development efforts.)

Comment: yes organisation_standard also contains the column id_standard. and adding standard table was a mistake in the first place but it is not affecting the query so i left it like this for the time being.

Comment: What datatype is question_text? If it is of an old BLOB type like text, or ntext the distinct would not work

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a `left join` and not an inner join change the inner joins into left joins and you will get just one row:

```
select distinct
    a.question_text, d.organisation_name
from
    question a
        left join
    standard b ON a.id_standard = b.id_standard
        left join
    organisation_standard c ON b.id_standard = c.id_standard
        left join
    organisation d ON c.id_organisation = d.id_organisation
where
    a.id_standard = 18
group by a.id_standard;
```

This diagram from [another so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) gives the difference between the different joins
[image]

Comment: My bad, a `group by` was needed, I have added it.